# How to I get the results of a call to a method that is located in a Mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I get the results of a method that I have defined inside a Mongoose model. I pass a parameter to the method. Here is what I have tried:

```
mySchema.methods.getStuff = function(id) {
    return this.model('coolSchema')
        .findOne({ _id : id })
        .exec(function (err, data) {
            console.log(data); // I can see that the data is retrieved
            return data;
        })
};
```

I then try to call this method by doing the following:

```
var cool = new coolSchema();

cool.getStuff(id, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data); // data is not being passed here as expected
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema method should have a callback argument, and call it with the results of the query.  The way it is written here you are just returning a query.  The callback function you pass as 2nd arg to `getStuff` is never looked at by that method.

Something like this should work out:

```
mySchema.methods.getStuff = function(id, cb) { //  <-- note getStuff takes a callback arg now
    return this.model('coolSchema')
        .findOne({ _id : id })
        .exec(function (err, data) {
            if (err) cb(err);  //   check for errors
            console.log(data); // I can see that the data is retrieved
            cb(null, data); //   <-- call the callback with the results 
        })
};
```

I assume you left off for brevity but it's also a good idea to check undefined/null `id` and that `cb` is actually callable.

You can also use a promise library to make a promisified version of the model:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
mySchema = Promise.promisify(mongoose.model('mySchema'));
```

Then in your schema method use the `Async` versions of the regular methods:

```
mySchema.methods.getStuff = function(id, cb) {
    return this.model('coolSchema')
        .findOneAsync({ _id : id })  //  <-- using 'promisified' version of method
        .then(function (id) {
            if (!id) throw new Error('ID wasn't found!')
            return id;
        })
        .catch(function(e){
          // db was down, etc. try to handle, or rethrow
          console.log('db error');
        })
};
```

then call `then`:

```
cool.getStuff(id).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data); 
})
.catch(function(e){}
    console.log('Error: '  + e.message);
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I prefer the first approach because it is simpler. I almost had it when trying on my own. The thing I was missing was ``null`` in the callback. It seems a bit arbitrary to need null as the first argument.

Comment: Cool!  Keep in mind the `cb(err, result)` is a Node.js convention, you'll be using that a lot when working with node